# Copy folder structure in r without its files

Tags: file-transfer, r

I want to copy some folders with their subfolders but not the files in these folders with R.
All i found is `file.copy` but this also copies the files.

Comment: Why R?  Something like `find -type d | xargs mkdir -p /newpath/{}` would be all that is required.

Comment: In the end I used a python script, but it would be nice to do it in R because it is part of a longer routine coded in R.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
You will have to select source dir and destination dir.

```
copydir = function(from=choose.dir(),to=choose.dir()){
  oridir=list.dirs(from,full.names = F)
  for(i in 2:length(oridir)){
    dir.create(paste0(to,'/',oridir[i]))
  }
}
copydir()
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?